# How to reduce SQL queries in only one in this case

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, having

I want to save the hassle of doing many querys for the following:

I have a table like this:

```
name, age
{
    Mike, 7
    Peter, 2
    Mario, 1
    Tony, 4
    Mary, 2
    Tom, 7
    Jerry, 3
    Nick, 2
    Albert, 22
    Steven, 7
}
```

And I want the following result:

```
Results(custom_text, num)
{
    1 Year, 1
    2 Year, 3
    3 Year, 1
    4 Year, 1
    5 Year, 0
    6 Year, 0
    7 Year, 3
    8 Year, 0
    9 Year, 0
    10 Year, 0
    More than 10 Year, 1
}
```

I know how to do this but in 11 queries :( But how to simplify it?

**EDIT:**

Doing the following, I can obtain the non zero values, but I need the zeroes in the right places.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS AgeCount
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Age
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: you're conflating three issues. The first concerns simple aggregation - I guess you know how to do that. The second is a simple case statement; again I guess you know how to do that. The third issue concerns the handling of absent results. This is a display issue. Generally, issues of data display are best handled in application level code (e.g. Php)

Comment: I guess I can add the custom string with PHP, but, how to obtain the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below query but it `will not show the gaps` if you want gaps then the use [Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29336556/3208640):

```
select t.txt, count(t.age) from 
(select 
  case 
      when age<11 then concat(age ,' year') 
      else 'more than 10' 
  end txt, age
from your_table)t
group by t.txt
order by 1
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3a26/41)

Comment: I have a litle question, if I have an existing query, and I want to apply your code to the table outputed by my existing query, what I must change? Actually I have the `FROM` and the `WHERE` blocks of that query, I have explained well?

Comment: it may depends on your query, but wrapping your query into parenthesis instead of your_table may solve it

Comment: I will create another question on StackOverflow, and I will paste the link here, because is a related question.

Comment: You know. if it's different than this question and answers in this question will not solve it then post it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join` and a subquery to get what you want:

```
select coalesce(concat(ages.n, ' year'), 'More than 10 year') as custom_text,
       count(*)
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all
      select 9 union all select 10 union all select null
     ) ages left join
     tabla t
     on (t.age = ages.n or ages.n is null and t.age > 10)
group by ages.n;
```

EDIT:

I think the following is a better way to do this query:

```
select (case when least(age, 11) = 11 then 'More than 10 year'
             else concat(age, ' year')
        end) as agegroup, count(name)
from (select 1 as age, NULL as name union all
      select 2, NULL union all
      select 3, NULL union all
      select 4, NULL union all
      select 5, NULL union all 
      select 6, NULL union all
      select 7, NULL union all
      select 8, NULL union all
      select 9, NULL union all
      select 10, NULL union all
      select 11, NULL 
      union all
      select age, name
      from tabla t
     ) t
group by least(age, 11);
```

Basically, the query need a `full outer join` and MySQL does not provide one.  However, we can get the same result by adding in extra values for each age, so we know something is there.  Then because `name` is `NULL`, the `count(name)` will return `0` for those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this query for required output.
SQL FIDDLE link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e52a/6

```
    select coalesce(concat(ages.n, ' year'), 'More than 10 year') as       custom_text,
    count(t.age) from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10 union all select null ) ages left join tabla t 
    on (case when ages.n<11 then t.age = ages.n else t.age > 10 end)
    group by ages.n;
```