# Issue combining two SQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

Hi everybody I'm trying to combine two `MySQL` queries into only one.

I have two blocks, the `FROM` and the `WHERE`, I think they are the only ones needed in my case.

FROM:

```
FROM table1, table2, table3, table4, table5
```

WHERE:

```
WHERE field1 = 1
  AND (field2 = 3 OR field2 = 4)
  AND (table5.field3 <= 100000)
  AND (table5.field4 >= 1)
  AND (table5.field5 >= 1)
  AND (table5.field6 >= 60)
  AND table5.field2 = table4.id
  AND table5.field7 = table3.field8
  AND table3.field9 = table1.field10
  AND table3.field11 = table2.field12
```

And the other query is this:

```
select t.txt, count(t.age) from 
(select 
  case 
      when age<11 then concat(age ,' year') 
      else 'more than 10' 
  end txt, age
from your_table)t
group by t.txt
order by 1
```

Thanks to [@Farhęg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3208640/farh%C4%99g)

I want that `your_table` is the result table of the query 1, or with restrictions `FROM` and `WHERE` that I already have.

How can I combine the two queries? Thanks!

Comment: what is the combined output supposed to look like? and the full first query would be helpful

Comment: @pala_ this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336431/how-to-reduce-sql-queries-in-only-one-in-this-case/

Comment: You are welcome, I'm also pleased with the mention, but first:I didn't get you well, second: it depends on your query you may wrap the query inside parenthesis and use it instead of your_table.

Comment: just replace your_table with the contents of the entire first query, wrapped in (). eg from your_table becomes from (select ...)

Comment: You think it's enough with just concatenate the `FROM` and the `WHERE` blocks (in that order). replacing `your_table`?

Comment: In this case, `age` is `table5.field4`.

Comment: if your_table needs to be the result of query 1, then you need to replace it with the entire query, not just the from and where parts.

Comment: No, I want the output of query two, the Farhęg's code output result.

Comment: you may also use direct joins instead of : using subquery instead of your_table

Comment: Please, write it as an answer, I'm not a SQL expert, I'm self taught enthusiast.

Comment: I have to know the structures of tables and see the query that you want to combine

Comment: can you come to the chat, I don't know how

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74065/discussion-between-alessadro-and-farheg).